# writing an embedded python dictionary to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

**Objective**: I need to take a python dictionary and export it to an excel workbook.
Here is the dictionary:

```
graph = {'Age':{'0-30':100,'31-50':106,'51-60':117,'60+':90},
     'Sex':{'Male':80,'Female':125,'Unknown':100},
     'Income':{'<25k':160,'25-75':110,'75-175':100,'>175':80},
     'Rent':{'1':160,'0':40},
     'Pets':{'Dog':120,'Cat':110,'Duck':80,'Other':50}}
```

Here is what I would like it to look like. Ideally with up to 4 key-value pairs across at one time.

[image]
Here is what I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(graph)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('index_vs_total.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook=writer.book
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='index_vs_total',startrow=3, index=True)
writer.save()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below:

For columns:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('index_vs_total.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
i = 0
for k,v in graph.items():
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({k:v})
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='index_vs_total',startcol=i, index=True)
    i=i+ dataframe.shape[1]+2
writer.save()
```

Output:
[image]

For rows:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('index_vs_total.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
i = 0 #set the startrow
for k,v in graph.items():
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({k:v})
    dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='index_vs_total',startrow=i, index=True)
    i=i+ len(dataframe)+2
writer.save()
```

---

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try `df.to_csv`('name', index=False)

Comment: This is the same thing that I have now. It becomes unreadable as the number of key-value pairs becomes large.  That's why I want to show the values right next to the key.

Comment: Which key? I dont see one

Comment: Age,Sex, Income are the keys.  Right under each key I want to see their values, ideally like I specified above although anky's answer below is good enough for starting.